# Turning project data into a relationship matrix

Tags: python, matrix, social-networking, stata

My data set a list of people either working together or alone.

I have have a row for each project and columns with names of all the people who worked on that project. If column 2 is the first empty column given a row it was a solo job, if column 4 is the first empty column given a row then there were 3 people working together.

My goal is to find which people have worked together, and how many times, so I want all pairs in the data set, treating A working with B the same as B working with A.

From this a square N x N would be created with every actor labeling the column and row and in cell (A,B) and (B,A) would have how many times that pair worked together, and this would be done for every pair.

I know of a 'pretty' quick way to do it in Excel but I want it automated, hopefully in Stata or Python, just in case projects are added or removed I can just 1-click the re-run and not have to re-do it every time.

An example of the data, in a comma delimited fashion:

```
A
A,B
B,C,E
B,F
D,F
A,B,C
D,B
E,C,B
X,D,A
```

Hope that helps!

Brice.
    F,D
    B
    F
    F,X,C
    C,F,D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would get you started?

```
import csv
import collections
import itertools

grid = collections.Counter()

with open("connect.csv", "r", newline="") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for line in reader:
        # clean empty names
        line = [name.strip() for name in line if name.strip()]
        # count single works
        if len(line) == 1:
            grid[line[0], line[0]] += 1
        # do pairwise counts
        for pair in itertools.combinations(line, 2):
            grid[pair] += 1
            grid[pair[::-1]] += 1

actors = sorted(set(pair[0] for pair in grid))

with open("connection_grid.csv", "w", newline="") as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow([''] + actors)
    for actor in actors:
        line = [actor,] + [grid[actor, other] for other in actors]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

[edit: modified to work under Python 3.2]

The key modules are (1)`csv`, which makes reading and writing csv files much simpler; (2) `collections`, which provides an object called a `Counter` -- like a `defaultdict(int)`, which you could use if your Python doesn't have `Counter`, it's a dictionary which automatically generates default values so you don't have to, and here the default count is 0; and (3) `itertools`, which has a `combinations` function to get all the pairs.

which produces

```
,A,B,C,D,E,F,X
A,1,2,1,1,0,0,1
B,2,1,3,1,2,1,0
C,1,3,0,1,2,2,1
D,1,1,1,0,0,3,1
E,0,2,2,0,0,0,0
F,0,1,2,3,0,1,1
X,1,0,1,1,0,1,0
```

You could use `itertools.product` to make building the array a little more compact, but since it's only a line or two I figured it was as simple to do it manually.

Comment: Your method produces a CSV which would be helpful, but why is it that if I run this exact code I get errors? I am relatively new to Python, and really only need this output. Am I missing a generic command in my module?

Comment: @BoSox: no, it's because you didn't mention you were using Python 3.2, and I assumed (being older than I should be) that you were using 2.7.  Things have changed a little; give me a sec.

Comment: This is great!! Thanks so much, is there a way to pick an answer as the best one? Lastly, if you do not mind, it does produce an extra column and row. This is probably because there are 3 columns and if A works alone (1,1) will have an A but (1,2) and (1,3) will have a blank.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your final sentence.

Comment: I was unsure regarding why I get a row with no header with a bunch of numbers and a column with no header with a bunch of numbers, I thought it had to do with the following spaces: The CSV I pulling the data from is a 14X3 at the moment, with each row representing a project. If a project is worked on by one person then the first column of that row has the person's name (e.g., A), and the two cells to the right (that would be first a second and third person is blank). Was wondering how to get created CSV to look like what you get produced, with no extra column or row.

Comment: @BoSox: oh, I see.  Your example doesn't have any extra commas.  We just have to get rid of the spaces before doing any work.  See my one-line edit.

Comment: I get I should also ask, in case it is ever needed how to make the diagonal (i.e., a person working a project alone) actually be the number of projects they have done alone and not 0. Thanks again for your help and generosity.

Comment: @BoSox: modified.  I would definitely recommend looking into `pandas` too (recommended by another answer) -- it's a very handy library.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted! Thanks again! I will definitely look into Pandas, do you have any recommendation for someone new to Python a good resource to start with (i.e., the knowledge to be able to have answered this question).

Comment: So, I have been playing with this and I have a couple of questions: If I had a column with months and years, is it possible to make a matrix spreadsheet for each month year? (i.e., for 2011, I would have 12 matrices)? Lastly, for whatever breakdown I use is is possible to make a variable, the combination of two names (e.g., A and B), AB, that will list how many times A and B worked together?

Answer (score 0):

If I were to keep this project around for a while, I'd implement a database and then create the matrix you're talking about from a query against that database.

You have a `Project` table (let's say) with one record per project, an `Actor` table with one row per person, and a `Participant` table with a record per project for each actor that was in that project.  (Each record would have an `ID`, a `ProjectID`, and an `ActorID`.)

From your example, you'd have 14 `Project` records, 7 `Actor` records (A through F, and X), and 31 `Participant` records.

Now, with this set up, each cell is a query against this database.

To reconstruct the matrix, first you'd add/update/remove the appropriate records in your database, and then rerun the query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Python Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this. It enables a slick solutions for formatting your adjacency matrix, and it will make any statistical calculations much easier too. You can also directly extract the matrix of values into a [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) array, for doing eigenvalue decompositions or other graph-theoretical procedures on the group clusters if needed later.

I assume that the example data you listed is saved into a file called `projects_data.csv` (it doesn't need to actually be a .csv file though). I also assume no blank lines between each observations, but this is all just file organization details.

Here's my code for this:

```
# File I/O part
import itertools, pandas, numpy as np
with open("projects_data.csv") as tmp:
    lines = tmp.readlines()
lines = [line.split('\n')[0].split(',') for line in lines]
# Unique letters
s = set(list(itertools.chain(*lines)))


# Actual work.
df = pandas.DataFrame(
                      np.zeros((len(s),len(s))), 
                      columns=sorted(list(s)), 
                      index=sorted(list(s))
                     )

for line in lines:
    if len(line) == 1:
        df.ix[line[0],line[0]] += 1 # Single-person projects
    elif len(line) > 1:
        # Get all pairs in multi-person project.
        tmp_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(line, 2))

        # Append pair reversals to update (i,j) and (j,i) for each pair.
        tmp_pairs = tmp_pairs + [pair[::-1] for pair in tmp_pairs]
        for pair in tmp_pairs:
            df.ix[pair[0], pair[1]] +=1
            # Uncomment below if you don't want the list
            # comprehension method for getting the reverals.
            #df.ix[pair[1], pair[0]] +=1 

# Final product
print df.to_string()

   A  B  C  D  E  F  X
A  1  2  1  1  0  0  1
B  2  1  3  1  2  1  0
C  1  3  0  1  2  2  1
D  1  1  1  0  0  3  1
E  0  2  2  0  0  0  0
F  0  1  2  3  0  1  1
X  1  0  1  1  0  1  0
```

Now you can do a lot of stuff for free, like see the total number of project partners (repeats included) for each participant:

```
>>> df.sum()
A     6
B    10
C    10
D     7
E     4
F     8
X     4
```

Comment: I figured it out, but I get an extra random row and column that has no label...any ideas why?

Comment: Possibly if your data file has spaces in it. I assumed no empty space lines. But you should be able to modify the code above for your specific purposes; the point here was just to show the basic idea, not to totally do your work.

Comment: Yeah, I confirmed. If there are totally blank lines in the input file, it will give you an extra column and row. One way to prevent this is to use the following: `lines = [line.split('\n')[0].split(',') for line in lines if len(line.split('\n')[0]) > 0]` instead of what is currently in there, just after the `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you don't have thousands of people working together in these projects. This implementation is pretty simple.

```
fp = open('projects.cvs')

# counts how many times each pair worked together
pairs = {}

# each element of `project` is a person
for project in (p[:-1].split(',') for p in fp):
    project.sort()

    # someone is alone here
    if len(project) == 1:
        continue

    # iterate over each pair 
    for i in range(len(project)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(project)):
            pair = (project[i], project[j])
            # increase `pairs` counter
            pairs[pair] = pairs.get(pair, 0) + 1

from pprint import pprint
pprint(pairs)
```

It outputs:

```
{('A', 'B'): 1,
 ('B', 'C'): 2,
 ('B', 'D'): 1,
 ('B', 'E'): 1,
 ('B', 'F'): 2,
 ('C', 'E'): 1,
 ('C', 'F'): 1,
 ('D', 'F'): 1}
```